# Null is not an object Error when working with tables (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a filter for my table, the table elements are dynamically inserted by reading from firebase database.

I have the following input which I want to use as a filter for my table:

```
<input type="number" id = "myInput" onkeyup="checkLoad()" placeholder="Search for Job Number">
```

and the following is corresponding javascript functionality:

```
function checkLoad(){
  window.addEventListener('load',Loaded,false);
}
// every key up not entering loaded 
function Loaded(){
  var input  = document.getElementById("myInput");
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var td, textValue;

  // loop through tr and hide ones which do not match query
  for(var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++){
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I did not always have the checkLoad() function trigger onkeyup, what I had before was the Loaded function was called Filter() and onkeyup I called Filter(), but this gave me the null error.

Now I do not get the Null error, but, I added a simple console.log statement in the Loaded function and It seems like I do not even enter the Loaded method at all.

Comment: By the time you type into an input box the page has already loaded. You arnt checking loaded with your checkLoad you are just adding an event listener to the page load event which has already happened.

Comment: @GifCo So then, when can I simply call my Filter() (same thing as Loaded) on the onkeyup event?   Because I tried that and it didn't seem to work  as I  get the Null is not an Object error

Comment: try calling Loaded directly with onkeyup="Loaded"  notice there are no parens ()

Comment: @GifCo That makes no sense. If you don't use parens, it doesn't call the function.

Comment: Which line was getting the `null is not an object` error?

Comment: @Barmar of course it calls the function. It calls it on keyup. Adding the parens executes the function immediately.

Comment: Probably one of your `getElementById()` calls was failing. It returns `null` when that happens.

Comment: @GifCo You're thinking of an assignment like `el.onkeyup = Loaded;`. That's not how `onkeyup="Loaded"` works in HTML attributes. The attribute contains JavaScript code to be executed, so it needs the parens.

Comment: @Barmar The line: ```var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");``` Gets the null  error if I am to just  call Loaded() onkeyup

Comment: THat means that `document.getElementById("myTable");` couldn't find the table. Check that the ID is correct.

Comment: @GifCo If I just call onkeyup = Loaded , then I do not get a null error but also the Loaded function is never even entered

Comment: @Barmar oh man what a simple mistake, you are  right I by mistakenly had the ID wrong, thank you so much!

Comment: For frog snacks!! Thats what you get for writing to much react! lol